# Bootstrap table layout

Tags: css, user-interface, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to achieve the setup illustrated below with Bootstrap 3, but I can't quite find a way to do it, especially to keep it responsive. I looked at panels and tables, etc. but then tend to not have really worked out great so far.

[image]

Comment: You add class **table-responsive** ?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Show your HTML/CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out in the end. Just took a bit of messing around with rows within the panels.

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist">

    <div class="panel panel-default container-fluid">
        <div class="row panel-heading ">
            <div class="col-sm-1 pull-left"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">Asset ID</div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-12">Status</div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-12">Asset Nodes</div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12">Manage</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-default container-fluid">
        <div class="panel-heading row" role="tab" id="headingOne">
            <div class="col-xs-1">
                <div data-toggle="collapse" class="handpointer glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></div>

            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                <a href="#">xxx</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-12">Normal</div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-12">?</div>
            <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-12"><a class="btn btn-xs btn-default" href="#" role="button">button</a></div>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
            <div class="panel-body">
                dsfsdfd
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/NLxmcWu4SJ